# how do i write not equal to in a doctrine where clause?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I hope someone can help me, i'm writing a custom query in my repository and i'd like to do the below:-

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('a')
->from('entity', 'a')
->where('a.deleted not 1') /// how do you write NOT??? i've tried <> etc 
->getQuery();
```

How do i perform the above?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Francesco's answer is correct. It all depends on your will to use either the expression builder or a high level solution.

For your particular case you can choose one of the two.

Expression builder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$expr = $queryBuilder->expr();

$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select('a')
    ->from('entity', 'a')
    ->where($expr->neq('a.deleted', 1))
    ->getQuery();
```

For high level solution see Rawkode's answer. Except changing the `!=` to `<>` or using `a.deleted = 0`.

Better yet would be parametrizing this with Doctrine

```
->where('a.deleted = :deleted')
->setParameter('deleted', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use **neq()** like in the following example:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t');
$expr = $query->expr();
$orx = $expr->orX();

$orx->add($expr->neq('t.pageTitle', $expr->literal('value1')));
$orx->add($expr->neq('t.metaDescription', $expr->literal('value2')));

$query->andWhere($orx);
```

The above code produces:

```
AND (
    t1_.page_title <> 'value1' 
    OR t1_.meta_description <> 'value2'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('a')
->from('entity', 'a')
->where('a.deleted != 1') /// how do you write NOT??? i've tried <> etc 
->getQuery();
```

'!=' means not equal

Comment: I have changed my code to use != and it does not return any results at all now, the deleted field is a INT, the field values is set to null until the record is deleted, then the field is set to 1, therefore i want to return every record that is not equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

!= means not equal to
!=== means not identical to

Comment: I have changed my code to use != and it does not return any results at all now, the deleted field is a INT, the field values is set to null until the record is deleted, then the field is set to 1, therefore i want to return every record that is not equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('u.id', 1)
    ->getQuery();
```

I'm not sure about not equal operator in query building. But, this may help you.
BTW, I'm also looking for better answer.